# Oauth error message "Missing message or attachment", "type":"OAuthException","code":100 in android while Facebook post on friends wall

Tags: android, facebook, oauth, friend, invitation

I want to give user of my application an option to log-in into my application using Facebook account. And I'm able to do that using below code.

```
String[] permissions = { "offline_access", "publish_stream", "user_photos", "publish_checkins", "photo_upload" };
mFacebook.authorize(FacebookLogin.this, permissions, new LoginDialogListener());

public final class LoginDialogListener implements DialogListener {
    public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
        new MyAsyncGetJsonFromFacebbok(FacebookLogin.this).execute();
    }

    public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {
        Toast.makeText(FacebookLogin.this, "Something went wrong. Please try again.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.v("onFacebookError FacebookLogin", error.toString());
    }

    public void onError(DialogError error) {
        Toast.makeText(FacebookLogin.this, "Something went wrong. Please try again.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.v("onError FacebookLogin", error.toString());
    }

    public void onCancel() {
        Toast.makeText(FacebookLogin.this, "Something went wrong. Please try again.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    public class MyAsyncGetJsonFromFacebbok extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, JSONObject> {
        Context context;
        JSONObject jsonObj = null;

        public MyAsyncGetJsonFromFacebbok(Context context_) {
            this.context = context_;
        }

        @Override
        protected JSONObject doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                jsonObj = com.facebook.android.Util.parseJson(mFacebook.request("me"));
            } catch (FacebookError e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return jsonObj;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject jsonObj) {
            try {
                String facebookID = jsonObj.getString("id");
                String firstName = jsonObj.getString("first_name");
                String lastName = jsonObj.getString("last_name");
                Toast.makeText(FacebookLogin.this, "Thank you for Logging In, " + firstName + " " + lastName + "!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
                SessionStore.save(mFacebook, FacebookLogin.this);
                storeDataInSharedPreferrence(facebookID, firstName, lastName);
                sendInvitationToFriends(facebookID);
                startNextActivity();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now I'm trying to give invitation to all my Facebook friends to join my android application. For that I'm trying a code from this link, [send an invitation to facebook friends to join my website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6747935/send-an-invitation-to-facebook-friends-to-join-my-website), and modified code of it(because it wasn't working), now the code is:

```
String response = mFacebook.request((userID == null) ? "me" : userID);
            Bundle params = new Bundle();

            params.putString("message", "msg");
            params.putString(mFacebook.getAccessToken(), "msg");

            params.putByteArray("message", "message goes here".getBytes());
            params.putByteArray("link", "http://mysite.com".getBytes());
            params.putByteArray("caption", "Click the link".getBytes());
            params.putByteArray("description", "description of link".getBytes());
            params.putByteArray("name", "name of link".getBytes());
            params.putByteArray("picture", "http://url.to.my.picture/pic.jpg".getBytes());

            response = mFacebook.request(((userID == null) ? "me" : userID) + "/feed", params, "POST");
```

but its giving the error

```
12-03 19:46:04.552: D/Tests(873): {"error":{"message":"(#100) Missing message or attachment","type":"OAuthException","code":100}}
```

So please help me to remove this error.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using `params.putByteArray` for text fields? I understand the "picture" field. But a simple `params.putString` will suffice the "message", "link", "caption", "description" and "name" fields.

Also, you are passing the "message" parameter twice. 
Once here: `params.putString("message", "msg");`

and another here: `params.putByteArray("message", "message goes here".getBytes());`

You code should essentially look like this:

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("message", "msg");
params.putString(mFacebook.getAccessToken(), "msg");

params.putString("message", "message goes here".getBytes()); // CHOOSE FROM EITHER THE ONE ON THIS LINE OR THIS ONE: params.putString("message", "msg");
params.putString("link", "http://mysite.com".getBytes());
params.putString("caption", "Click the link".getBytes());
params.putString("description", "description of link".getBytes());
params.putString("name", "name of link".getBytes());
params.putByteArray("picture", "http://url.to.my.picture/pic.jpg".getBytes());
```

I use the exact same code (well, almost anyway) for my app and it works just fine. That being said, I am not so sure about this one: `params.putByteArray("picture", "http://url.to.my.picture/pic.jpg".getBytes());`

I only upload photos from either the Gallery or the Camera.